# Weather app shows animation on one iPhone 4 but not another

Tags: iphone, ios

My husband and I have identical iPhone 4's.  His shows animations on the weather app, like lightening, rain, moving clouds.  Mine doesn't.  How come?  Our phones are exactly the same phones.

Comment: how identical are they? same iOS?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

The "Reduce Motion" setting in accessibility controls the movement in Weather.